# DrawString bug with certain Cyrillic symbols drawn with big emSize

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have very simple application, printing one large cyrillic symbol on bitmap. Cyrillic alphabet has 33 letters and 31 of them correctly printed, but letters 'Э' and 'Я' (codes are 1069 [(see here)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/042d/index.htm) and 1071 [(see here)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/042f/index.htm)) throw 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

**StackTrace:**

```
   in System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)    
   in System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(String s, Font font, Brush brush, RectangleF layoutRectangle, StringFormat format)  
   in System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(String s, Font font, Brush brush, Single x, Single y)  
   in textTest.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in w:\Delete\textTest\textTest\Form1.cs:line 27
```

Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1000, 2000);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                try
                {
                    g.DrawString((char)1069+"", new Font("Times New Roman", 100f, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.White, 100, 100);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works fine for me. You'll need to add more information about your environment etc. if you hope to get help :)

Comment: No repro either, can't say I expected one.  The more likely cause is running out of GDI handles, the OS gets upset when you have 10,000 of them or the desktop heap is exhausted.  Diagnose with Task Manager, add the USER Objects and GDI Objects columns.  Steadily climbing numbers spell doom.

Comment: Windows 7, VS 2013 community edition 4, .Net 4.5. The culture is ('ru'), but I also tried switching to 'invariant' (didn't help).

Comment: I replaced "Э" with its code in my code sample to avoid possible issues related to web-browser encoding.

Comment: I added some links to unicode character lists, may be helpful for others. I also agree with HansPassant - the problem may lie elsewhere. Handles are probable. For example, even in this simple code snippet you showed us, there's already a possible handle leak: `new Font(...)` is from System.Drawing, it may allocate a handle, and you just create it and don't Dispose() it anywhere. If you have more of such bugs in the actual code, you most probably ran out of handles. They are **global**, so one app that leaks handles may starve other unrelated apps.